# Пул временных портов

Tags: c#, windows, сеть, port

Возникла задача по реализации OAuth fat клиента при уже существующем серверном приложении. Проблема в том, что клиент может быть подключен к серверу только после регистрации в определенной системе с указанием не только адреса подключения, но и клиентского порта.

То есть

1. Админы регистрируют адрес клиента и порт (например, localhost:12346)
2. Клиент запускает легковесный http сервер на localhost:12346
3. Клиент после этого шлет запрос на сервер с параметром в запросе redirectUri=localhost:12346
4. Сервер делает что надо, проверяет регистрации и отдает редирект на указанный localhost:12346
5. Клиент считывает что ему надо, закрывает веб сервер и работает дальше.

Такой вот незамысловатый callback сервер для реализации OAuth в системе. 
Проблема тут в том, что, получается, надо хардкодить определенный порт на всех клиентах. Предустановленное ПО на клиенте - неизвестно. Гарантий, что порт при попытке запуска на клиенте, будет свободен - нет.

Потому возникает вопрос, если ли какие то пулы портов, предназначенные именно для таких временных подключений?

Пока что я склоняюсь к [динамическому порту](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82), заререзвированному в [iana](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=1) - то есть что то между 49152 — 65535, но как именно выбрать нужный порт пока затрудняюсь. Чтобы снизить риски, есть возможность указать до 4 портов на приложение, но надо выбрать такие порты, при которых вероятность, что они все будут одновременно заняты на любом из клиентов минимальна.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101019/discussion-on-question-by-tym32167---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Использование встраиваемого браузера

Если есть возможно использовать встроенный браузер (WebKit в виде [СefSharp](http://cefsharp.github.io/), или хотя бы WebBrowser Control), то порт слушать необязательно. Код возвращается в виде GET-параметра, и его можно забрать напрямую из URL в момент редиректа.

В этом случае вместо localhost:port стоит указать Return URL вида urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob или urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto - так делает, например, [стандартный клиент для AzureAD](https://docs.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop), примерно так же [обычно интегрируются с гуглом на декстопе](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp).

Основной минус - встроенный бразуер или уже безнадежно устарел (WebBrowser) или весит достаточно много (WebKit).

#### Использование системного браузера + кастомной схемы

В [реестре можно зарегистрировать кастомную схему](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) url (mysuperscheme://), по навигацию на которую будет запущено ваше приложение. Примерно так сделан вход в Slack. Из недостатков - будет запущен новый экземпляр, и взаимодействие между ними придется организовать вручную. К тому же, некоторые бразуеры спрашивают подтверждение при запуске приложения по кастомной схеме.

#### Разделяемый порт 80

Стандартный [System.Net.HttpListener](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8) позволяет сразу нескольким приложениям слушать на 80 порту, одновременно с IIS. Можно выбрать достаточно уникальный URL Prefix - и с большой вероятностью решить одновременно и проблему предсказуемости порта, и проблему предсказуемости настроек firewall. Из минусов - может быть занято все сразу одним сайтом на /, или каким-нибудь Skype.

#### Мне повезет

Попробуйте просто опросить коллег (вдруг кто-то уже реализовал такую схему) и выбросить из пула портов те, на которые завязались они. Если есть возможность - соберите статистику по открытым портам с целевых машин. Потом выберите 4 разных порта и надейтесь, что вам повезет. В качестве доп. мер, если ваше приложение зажали в угол - отбивайтесь и предлагайте закрыть приложения-конкуренты.